# Changing between calculations according to choose from dropdown

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am doing as a school project Unity aplication that transfers units into another units by your choosing. I have dropdown script that changes text accordingly to what you choose from the dropdown menu. I need on every instance of a dropdown menu different calculation (for example if I choose kilometer, I need calculations for transfering the kilometer into another units).
(btw do not be surprised by some words...I am from czechia so something is in czech)

**The dropdown script is like this:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class DropDownDélka : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI output;

    public void HandleInputData(int val)
    {
        if (val == 0)
        {
            output.text = "Délka";
        }

        if (val == 1)
        {
            output.text = "Kilometr";
        }

        if (val == 2)
        {
            output.text = "Metr";
        }
```

...and so on...

**If I pick the Kilometer from a dropdown I need it to use this:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class KilometrVýpočet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI kilometr;
    public TextMeshProUGUI metr;
    public TextMeshProUGUI decimetr;
    public TextMeshProUGUI centimetr;
    public TextMeshProUGUI milimetr;
    public TMP_InputField inputField;

    public void StoreInput()
    {
        kilometr.text = inputField.text;
        
        float metrA = Convert.ToSingle(inputField.text);
        float metrB = 1000f;
        float metrR = metrA * metrB;
        metr.text = metrR.ToString();

        float decimetrA = Convert.ToSingle(inputField.text);
        float decimetrB = 10000f;
        float decimetrR = decimetrA * decimetrB;
        decimetr.text = decimetrR.ToString();

        float centimetrA = Convert.ToSingle(inputField.text);
        float centimetrB = 100000f;
        float centimetrR = centimetrA * centimetrB;
        centimetr.text = centimetrR.ToString();

        float milimetrA = Convert.ToSingle(inputField.text);
        float milimetrB = 1000000f;
        float milimetrR = milimetrA * milimetrB;
        milimetr.text = milimetrR.ToString();
    }
}
```

But I did not find a solution for how to do it. I have calculation script for every unit and now I just need the aplication to change between them according to what I choose from the dropdown. I tried many things but without succes. You know...I am just learning.
Thank you guys for any help.

---

---

**EDIT:** I've played with the code a littlebit and now it looks like this:

**First script:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class DropDownDélka : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI output;
    public TMP_Dropdown dropdown;

    Number number = new Number();

    public void DropDownHandle(int val)
    {
        if (val == 0)
        {
            output.text = "Délka";

            number.Num = 0;
            Debug.Log("Num = " + number.Num);
        }

        if (val == 1)
        {
            output.text = "Kilometr";

            number.Num = 1;
            Debug.Log("Num = " + number.Num);
        }

        if (val == 2)
        {
            output.text = "Metr";

            number.Num = 2;
            Debug.Log("Num = " + number.Num);
        }
```

...and so on...

```
public class Number
{
    public int _num;
    public int Num
    {
        get
        {
            return _num;
        }
        set
        {
            _num = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Second script:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class DélkaVýpočty : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI kilometr;
    public TextMeshProUGUI metr;
    public TextMeshProUGUI decimetr;
    public TextMeshProUGUI centimetr;
    public TextMeshProUGUI milimetr;
    public TMP_InputField inputField;

    Number num = new Number();

    Jednotky jednotky = new Jednotky();

    public void If()
    {
        if (num._num == 0) { return; }

        if (num._num == 1)
        {
            Debug.Log("_num = " + num._num);
            jednotky.km = true;
        }

        if (num._num == 2)
        {
            Debug.Log("_num = " + num._num);
            jednotky.m = true;
        }
```

...and so on...

```
public void Výpočty()
    {
        if (inputField.text != null)
        {

            if (jednotky.km == true)
            {
                kilometr.text = inputField.text;

                float metrA = Convert.ToSingle(inputField.text);
                float metrB = 1000f;
                float metrR = metrA * metrB;
                metr.text = metrR.ToString();

                float decimetrA = Convert.ToSingle(inputField.text);
                float decimetrB = 10000f;
                float decimetrR = decimetrA * decimetrB;
                decimetr.text = decimetrR.ToString();

                float centimetrA = Convert.ToSingle(inputField.text);
                float centimetrB = 100000f;
                float centimetrR = centimetrA * centimetrB;
                centimetr.text = centimetrR.ToString();

                float milimetrA = Convert.ToSingle(inputField.text);
                float milimetrB = 1000000f;
                float milimetrR = milimetrA * milimetrB;
                milimetr.text = milimetrR.ToString();
            }

            if (jednotky.m == true)
            {
                float kilometrA = Convert.ToSingle(inputField.text);
                float kilometrB = 1000f;
                float kilometrR = kilometrA / kilometrB;
                kilometr.text = kilometrR.ToString();

                metr.text = inputField.text;

                float decimetrA = Convert.ToSingle(inputField.text);
                float decimetrB = 10f;
                float decimetrR = decimetrA * decimetrB;
                decimetr.text = decimetrR.ToString();

                float centimetrA = Convert.ToSingle(inputField.text);
                float centimetrB = 100f;
                float centimetrR = centimetrA * centimetrB;
                centimetr.text = centimetrR.ToString();

                float milimetrA = Convert.ToSingle(inputField.text);
                float milimetrB = 1000f;
                float milimetrR = milimetrA * milimetrB;
                milimetr.text = milimetrR.ToString();
            }
```

...and so on...

```
public class Jednotky
{
    public bool km;
    public bool m;
    public bool dm;
    public bool cm;
    public bool mm;
}
```

But now when i click on button that is supposed to transfer the units it does literally NOTHING. I guess it is because of the booleans are for some reason never *true*. I used debug log to see if the *Num* and the dropdown is coded correctly and it is, so I really think that it has to be something with booleans :/.

**Again...glad for any help <3**

---

---

**EDIT 2:** I recreated the whole code and realized that I was a totall IDIOT and made so much unnecessary stuff :D. Anyways...down here is the final form that works just like I wanted it to work.

**First script:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class DropDownDélka : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI output;
    public TMP_Dropdown dropdown;

    public int Num;

    public void DropDownHandle(int val)
    {
        if (val == 0)
        {
            output.text = "Délka";

            Num = 0;
            Debug.Log("Num = " + Num);
        }

        if (val == 1)
        {
            output.text = "Kilometr";

            Num = 1;
            Debug.Log("Num = " + Num);
        }

        if (val == 2)
        {
            output.text = "Metr";

            Num = 2;
            Debug.Log("Num = " + Num);
        }
```

...and so on...

**Second script:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class DélkaVýpočty : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI kilometr;
    public TextMeshProUGUI metr;
    public TextMeshProUGUI decimetr;
    public TextMeshProUGUI centimetr;
    public TextMeshProUGUI milimetr;
    public TMP_InputField inputField;

    DropDownDélka dropDownDélka;

    public void Výpočty()
    {
        dropDownDélka = GetComponent<DropDownDélka>();

        Debug.Log("Num2 = " + dropDownDélka.Num);

        if (inputField.text != null)
        {

            if (dropDownDélka.Num == 1)
            {
                kilometr.text = inputField.text;

                float metrA = Convert.ToSingle(inputField.text);
                float metrB = 1000f;
                float metrR = metrA * metrB;
                metr.text = metrR.ToString();

                float decimetrA = Convert.ToSingle(inputField.text);
                float decimetrB = 10000f;
                float decimetrR = decimetrA * decimetrB;
                decimetr.text = decimetrR.ToString();

                float centimetrA = Convert.ToSingle(inputField.text);
                float centimetrB = 100000f;
                float centimetrR = centimetrA * centimetrB;
                centimetr.text = centimetrR.ToString();

                float milimetrA = Convert.ToSingle(inputField.text);
                float milimetrB = 1000000f;
                float milimetrR = milimetrA * milimetrB;
                milimetr.text = milimetrR.ToString();
            }

            if (dropDownDélka.Num == 2)
            {
                float kilometrA = Convert.ToSingle(inputField.text);
                float kilometrB = 1000f;
                float kilometrR = kilometrA / kilometrB;
                kilometr.text = kilometrR.ToString();

                metr.text = inputField.text;

                float decimetrA = Convert.ToSingle(inputField.text);
                float decimetrB = 10f;
                float decimetrR = decimetrA * decimetrB;
                decimetr.text = decimetrR.ToString();

                float centimetrA = Convert.ToSingle(inputField.text);
                float centimetrB = 100f;
                float centimetrR = centimetrA * centimetrB;
                centimetr.text = centimetrR.ToString();

                float milimetrA = Convert.ToSingle(inputField.text);
                float milimetrB = 1000f;
                float milimetrR = milimetrA * milimetrB;
                milimetr.text = milimetrR.ToString();
            }
```

...and so on...

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `SelectedIndexChanged` EventHandler for your dropbox to detect a change and then simply check the `SelectedIndex` of the dropbox and apply your calculations according.

**EDIT:** I believe `SelectedIndexChanged` is called `onValueChanged` in unity and `SelectedIndex` is just the `value` of the dropbox.

Comment: So..I tried to look into it but was not able to solve the problem...I tried so much things but none of them worked. As I said...I'm just learning...

Comment: @DEXX ok let's start from the beginning. Do you know what `Methods` are and how to call them? If so do you know how to call a `Method` from another `Class`? If you don't look it up.

Comment: Yes, I know what methods are and how to call them and yes, I know how to call them from another class. I've edited the code and now it looks to be ok, but now when i click on button that is supposed to transfer the units it does literally NOTHING. Could you please look into it??...I'd be really glad for that.

Comment: @DEXX set a **breakpoint** inside your `If()` Method to check if it ever gets fired. If not that is the problem.

Comment: OK, I've foud out that the the `If()` method doesn't ever get fired...as you said. I really do not know why.

Comment: @DEXX probably because you never call it in the first place. You would want to call it whenever the selected index of your dropbox is changed. This is where `onValueChanged` comes into play like I said in my answer. So want you have to do now is create an `onValueChanged` EventHandler for your dropbox and call the `If()` Method inside of that EventHandler. :)

Comment: Yes...that was the problem and I really do not know how did I miss that :DD. I had in the code so much stuff that was just unnecessary..like ALL of the bools. I remade the code and it now looks like the last edit. I didn't even use the `onValueChnage`. Thank you for your help tho <3. I just realized I was a totall idiot :D. Now it all works.

Answer (score 0):

**IF SOMEONE NEEDS THE EXACT THING I NEEDED AND SKIPPED THE LOOONG QUESTION...IN THE** *EDIT 2* **ARE THE FINAL, WOKING FORMS OF THE SCRIPTS**